# C++ : read binary files and extract the values

Tags: c++, file, binary

I would need a kick start for helping me to read my binary files in C++ and play around with the extracted values.
I basically know the structure of the file and the kind of data.
It consists in a fixed header and then events with several data I want to store in double type values.

```
# The data format is the following one
#;    It consists of a common header containing (4 + N_boards) 32-bit words:
#        
#;        Word 1 = Version
#;        Word 2 = Time base
#;        Word 3 = Number of events registered
#;        Word 4 = Number of boards (N_boards)
#;        Words 4+1 to 4+N_boards = Info about each board (I don't need to read this so I have to skip that)
#;        
#;    Then it follows the list of events, stored using 4 x 32 bits. I need to store this into double values.
#;    
#;        Word 1 --> Crate                ( 4 bits: 31-28)
#;                   Board                ( 6 bits: 27-22)
#;                   Channel              ( 6 bits: 21-16)
#;                   Timestamp bits 47-32 (16 bits: 15-0)
#;                   
#;        Word 2 --> Timestamp bits 31-0  (32 bits: 31-0) 
#;        
#;        Word 3  --> X position (5 bits: 20-16)
#;                    Y position (8 bits: 7-0)       
#;
#;        Word 4 --> A+B (16 bits: 31-16)
#;                   A   (16 bits: 15-0)
```

I succeeded to read the header correctly doing this :

```
ifstream input (BufferPath[i].c_str(), ios::binary);

input.seekg(0, ios::end);
end = input.tellg();
input.seekg(0, ios::beg);

// Read the 4 fixed elements of the header.
uint32_t nbEvents = 0;
uint32_t nbBoards = 0;
uint32_t timeBase = 0;
uint32_t version = 0;

input.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&version), sizeof(int32_t));
input.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&timeBase), sizeof(int32_t));
input.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&nbEvents), sizeof(int32_t));
input.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&nbBoards), sizeof(int32_t));
```

But then, I have much more difficulty to skip the rest of the header and read and isolate into separate values the data from my events. I thought about using a buffer to store everything but then how to split the stored values ?

```
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input), {});
```

As you can see I am a but confused about dealing with binary files so any help would be gladly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance :) !

Comment: I'd generally read the entire file into memory in a single operation and then use pointers to navigate around its insides.

Comment: You've already shown that read four words from the file. Now, in the rest of the header, you have a variable number of words. But, guess what? You read them ***exactly*** the same way. One word at a time! Using a `for` loop. Why do you think this has to be any more complicated than creating a vector, then using a `for` loop to read the exact number of words and add each one to the vector? What exactly are you "confused" about what seems to be a rather simple, straightforward, process?

Comment: For the rest of the header ok well this is not the problem, I just skip them with a for loop.. The real question is for my events (4x32 bits) : how do I extract the different values listed before from a single uint32_t ?
In other words, from word 1 that I read the same as before, how do I extract "crate", "board", "channel" and "timestamp" and store this into double.